# Messages counter is showing total number of messages instead of count for logged user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to display number of unread messages (if any) when user logs in. The problem is that when I log in with newly created account I got notification for X unread messages but there are none.

To explain it better. If `admin` send message to `user1` and `user1` isn't read it yet, when `user2` logs in it will have notification that there is 1 unread message. When `user1` read it the notification will disappear.

I have added this to my `ViewComposerServiceProvider` boot function

```
public function boot()
{

    dd(Auth::user()); <--- return NULL

    $unviewedCustomersMessagesCount = Message::where('read_state', '0')->where('from_admin', '1')->count();
    View::share('unviewedCustomersMessagesCount', $unviewedCustomersMessagesCount);
}
```

And then I simply show the counter in view.blade

```
{{ $unviewedCustomersMessagesCount }}
```

If need this is my `Message` model

```
class Message extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'messages';
    protected $primaryKey = 'message_id';

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function markAsRead() 
    {
        $this->read_state = '1';
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

And `User` model

```
class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use EntrustUserTrait;
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

        [....]  

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to count the messages for the user?

Controller

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
            $unviewedCustomersMessagesCount = Message::
            whereRaw('messages.message_id = (select max(message_id) from `messages` m2 where m2.user_id = messages.user_id)')
                ->where('read_state', '0')
                ->where('from_admin', '0')
                ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)
                ->count();

            View::share('unviewedCustomersMessagesCount',$unviewedCustomersMessagesCount );

    }            
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to pass the current user id to your query, remove the raw query

```
$currentUserId = Auth::user()->id;
$unviewedMessagesCount = Message::where('read_state', '0')
           ->where('from_admin', '0') 
           ->where('user_id',$currentUserId)             
           ->count();
```

Comment: u shoudnt create variable if u not using more then one

Comment: @Wraith can you explain your comment?

Comment: u should use  ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)   without create var currentUserId  u dont need use extra place in memory. or even auth()->user()->id is faster

Answer (score 0):

Try this..I think whereraw statement doesnt need in your situation.

```
view()->composer('layouts.master', function($view){

       $unviewedMessagesCount = 
      Message::where('read_state','=', '0')
           ->where('from_admin','=', '0')              
           ->count();                   
       $view->with('/', $unviewedMessagesCount );
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but I still see that I have messages even when I don't.

Comment: do you check your database too ?

Comment: Yes, when there is message `from_admin` to some user and the read state is `0` - all users are see notification for unread message

Comment: Still same. I think the problem maybe is in the boot function in general in `ViewComposerServiceProvider`.

Comment: may be .. By the way  in your blade 
{{ $unviewedCustomersMessagesCount }}?? or 
{{ $unviewedMessagesCount }}??


and in your boot function ->
 $view->with('$unviewedCustomersMessagesCount , $unviewedMessagesCount );  ?

Comment: From where will come `$unviewedCustomersMessagesCount`?

Comment: Yes..that is what i want to know..

$view->with('$unviewedCustomersMessagesCount , $unviewedMessagesCount );  ?

Comment: yess..can you change
 $view->with('/', $unviewedMessagesCount ); to 
$view->with('$unviewedCustomersMessagesCount , $unviewedMessagesCount );

Answer (score 0):

Try **casting** in `Messages` model, add `$cast` as:

```
protected $casts = ["read_state"=>"boolean", "from_admin"=>"integer"];
```

And in **view composer** try getting unread messages like:

```
$messages = \Auth::user()->messages()->where('read_state', false)->where('from_admin', 0)->count();
```

I am not sure whether `from_admin` is `boolean` or `integer`, you may change is as required in `$casts` and also use `true` or `false` or `0` inside the query.

Comment: It is `1` for admin and `0` for user

Comment: Got this error `Call to a member function messages() on null in `

Comment: There might be some problem as you're not able to get ```Auth::user()```, as you mentioned that it returns ```nulll``` in the issue description. Fixing it will fix your problem too.